# dynamic td blocking tr element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table that if I append the rows and table data the tr element content seems to be blocked I cannot even edit it from the console after it is created I think its blocked by the td

```
<table id='product_table' name='product_table' align='center'>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>


$("#product_table tbody")
  .append("<tr style='cursor:pointer;' data-id='21'>")
  .append("<td>data21</td>")
  .append("</tr>");

$("table#product_table tbody").on("click", "td", function() {
  console.log('wtf');
  console.log($(this).data('id'));
});
```

if I don't append the tr and td I can replace the td click selector with tr and it works, but if I append it nothing I do to the row has any affect even if I add css I can see it if I inspect it but it does not show or work like the cursor:pointer, but if I put them on the td element dynamically it works. any suggestions greatly appreciated.

new working code

```
      for (i=0;i<res.data.length;i++) {  

        $("#product_table tbody")
          .append("<tr style='cursor:pointer;' data-id='"+res.data[i].id+"'>" +  
              "<td>"+res.data[i].productNumber+"</td>" + 
              "<td>"+res.data[i].description+"</td>" + 
              "<td>"+res.data[i].productSize+"</td>" + 
              "<td>"+res.data[i].boxLength+"</td>" + 
              "<td>"+res.data[i].boxWidth+"</td>" + 
              "<td>"+res.data[i].boxHeight+"</td>" + 
              "<td>"+res.data[i].avgBilled+"</td>" + 
              "<td>"+res.data[i].productWeight+"</td>" + 
              "<td>"+res.data[i].boxQty+"</td>" + 
              "</tr>"
              );                       
      }


        $("table#product_table tbody").on("click", "tr", function(){
          console.log($(this).data());
        });
```

Comment: Your append syntax is incorrect. Each append is attempting to append to the tbody, not the element previously appended.

Comment: While chaining append is ok but you are appending to the same element each time. In your case, that's the tbody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The append is not properly formed when rendered. Please inspect the elements, you can find that the td is not inside the tr element.

```js
 $("#product_table tbody")
            .append("<tr style='cursor:pointer;' data-id='21'><td>data21</td></tr>")

        $("table#product_table tbody").on("click", "td", function () {
            console.log('Working.');
            console.log($(this).parent().data('id'));
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id='product_table' name='product_table' align='center'>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: cool i'll just put my td in the same append as my tr and all should be good. I didn't realize append was creating the elements like that

Answer (score 0):

Append doesnt not work in that way. When you append an element you only name it like ; append('div') and it opens and closes div automaticly. So you have to create element tr then add its attributes, after that you create td and set its innerHTML. Append td into tr and append tr into table. Dont use  /tr in append. Append puts dynamicly created element into target element's end.  Best way to create an element is document.createElement('tr');. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your event's 'this' is 'td', but you are trying to reference 'tr' which is a sibling of 'td', not a child. I changed to `$(this).siblings('tr').data('id')` and it works. Please see the snippet.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#product_table tbody")
    .append("<tr style='cursor:pointer;' data-id='21'>")
    .append("<td>data21</td>")
    .append("</tr>");

  $("#product_table tbody").on("click", "td", function() {
    console.log('wtf');
    console.log($(this).siblings('tr').data('id'));
  });
});
```

```css
#product_table {
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='product_table' name='product_table' align='center'>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yea I was changing the selector during troubleshooting, the td would fire but the tr would not after putting them on the same append the tr fired